# C++11 ways of finding if a type has member function or supports operator?

Tags: c++, c++11

There is a (seemingly) nice C++03 way of finding out if a type has a member function or operator:

https://github.com/jaredhoberock/is_call_possible/blob/master/is_call_possible.hpp

Is there no modern C++11 way to do this? It would be better not having to include any external code and use only the standard.

Comment: Is there a purpose to the question or are you just curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's pretty much the same way. More or less. Implementations vary, though you could replace some of the metafunctions used internally by that implementation with standard library traits. But there's no *simple* way of detecting if you can invoke a function on some type given some set of arguments.

That's for [concepts (PDF)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3701.pdf).

Answer (score 21):

This works with all test cases given in the GitHub (Demo: http://ideone.com/ZLGp4R):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename C, typename F, typename = void>
struct is_call_possible : public std::false_type {};

template <typename C, typename R, typename... A>
struct is_call_possible<C, R(A...),
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<R, void>::value ||
        std::is_convertible<decltype(
            std::declval<C>().operator()(std::declval<A>()...)
            //                ^^^^^^^^^^ replace this with the member you need.
        ), R>::value
    >::type
> : public std::true_type {};
```

Answer (score 17):

C++ 11 adds a new trick, which I often jokingly call "CFINAE" (compilation failure is not an error).

It makes use of the `decltype` operator and the regular properties of SFINAE.

Consider the following function:

```
template <typename X, typename Y>
static auto check(X& x, Y& y) -> decltype(x >> y);
```

It will be considered during overloading only if `X` and `Y` are types for which the
shift operator is defined. Add a regular catch-all overload for `check` and you have a mechanism to test whether an arbitrary expression can be compiled.

And indeed, this is the principle developed in the experimental [Origin](http://code.google.com/p/origin/) library by Andrew Sutton (one of the authors of the [Concepts Lite](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/02/concepts-lite-constraining-templates-with-predicates-andrew-sutton-bjarne-s) proposal). In fact, my example is taken straight from [here](http://code.google.com/p/origin/source/browse/trunk/origin/type/concepts.impl/traits.hpp) to implement the [Streamable](http://code.google.com/p/origin/source/browse/trunk/origin/type/concepts.test/streamable.cpp#53) concept.

I recommend the following presentation from GoingNative 2012 by Andrew Sutton and Bjarne Stroustrup where they give an introduction to the new take on concepts and the Origin library:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/A-Concept-Design-for-C-

Answer (score 2):

I use the following well known approach based on SFINAE:

```cpp
#define TYPE_SUPPORTS(ClassName, Expr)                         \
  template<typename U>                                         \
  struct ClassName                                             \
  {                                                            \
  private:                                                     \
    template<typename>                                         \
    static constexpr std::false_type test(...);                \
                                                               \
    template<typename T = U>                                   \
    static decltype((Expr), std::true_type{}) test(int) ;      \
                                                               \
  public:                                                      \
    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test<U>(0))::value; \
  };
```

The main purpose of the macro is to simplify adding type checks. The macro defines a struct that allows you to do an arbitrary check for a type `T`.

As an example, to check that `std::begin()` can be called for a type:

```cpp
namespace detail
{
  TYPE_SUPPORTS(SupportsBegin, std::begin(std::declval<T>()))
}

template<typename T>
constexpr bool supportsBegin()
{
   return detail::SupportsBegin<T>::value;
}
```

Of course, the `detail` namespace and function wrapper are all syntactic sugar, but improve the syntax a bit on the caller side.

Comment: very nice and concise explanation. just maybe that supportsBegin() function should and must return a constexpr bool to be usable in type traits