# Is it possible to write a macro existenceof(S,f) or hasfield(S,f) in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, template-meta-programming

I'm reasonably familiar with the standard metaprogramming solutions (e.g. [C++11 ways of finding if a type has member function or supports operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201329/c11-ways-of-finding-if-a-type-has-member-function-or-supports-operator)) which don't involve macro magic. However, I have a use-case involving the following convenience macros (drastically simplified for StackOverflow, of course, but imagine that this is for serialization or something)...

```
#define START(type) do { typedef type current; const char typeName[] = #type
#define OUTPUT(fieldname) \
    printf("type of %s.%s is %s\n", #type, #fieldname, \
        std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<current>().fieldname),int> ? "int" : "string")
#define END() } while (0)


struct Foo { int i; char *j; char *k; };
struct Bar { char *x; int y; };

START(Foo);
  OUTPUT(i);  // type of Foo.i is int
  OUTPUT(j);  // type of Foo.j is string
  OUTPUT(k);  // type of Foo.k is string
END();
START(Bar);
  OUTPUT(x);  // type of Bar.x is string
  OUTPUT(y);  // type of Bar.y is int
END();
```

But now let's say someone comes along and adds a new kind of data member to our schema: pairs of fields `(x, xLength)`. We want to change our convenience macros like this...

```
#define START(obj) do { const auto& current = (obj)
#define OUTPUT(fieldname) \
    printf("type of %s.%s is %s\n", #type, #fieldname, \
        std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<current>().fieldname),int> ? "int" :
        hasfield(current, fieldname##Length) ? "Pascal string" : "C string")
#define END() } while (0)


struct Baz { char *x, *y, *z; int xLength, zLength; };

START(Baz);
  OUTPUT(x);  // type of Baz.x is Pascal string
  OUTPUT(y);  // type of Baz.y is C string
  OUTPUT(z);  // type of Baz.z is Pascal string
END();
```

On my own I managed to come up with the following implementation of `hasfield` that works on Clang...

```
#define hasfield(classtype, fieldname)                                        \
    []() {                                                                    \
        struct X {                                                            \
            template<class T, int=sizeof(&T::fieldname)> static constexpr bool f(T*){ return true; } \
            static constexpr bool f(...) { return false; }                    \
        }; return X::f((classtype*)0);                                        \
    }()
```

...but unfortunately this appears to be due to [a bug in Clang](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.clang.scm/71482); according to the C++11 standard, local class `X` isn't allowed to have template members. Indeed, this code fails to compile with GCC.

So I'm stumped: Is it *possible* in C++11 to define the `OUTPUT` macro such that it'll do what I want?

Absolute constraints: No changing the struct definition of `Baz`. No hard-coding the `fieldname` ahead of time.

Nice-to-haves: A `hasfield(c,f)` macro that can be used in other contexts as well (as opposed to entwining the code directly into the `OUTPUT` macro). No assuming that `offsetof(c,fLength)==offsetof(c,f)+sizeof(std::declval<c>().f)`.

Comment: Not an answer at all, just a tip: you can simplify `sizeof(std::declval<T>().m)` to `sizeof(T::m)` (and similarly with `decltype`), even when `m` is a non-static data member.

Comment: i can imagine `typeid().name()` and `__cxa_demangle` could come handy when serializing. just a tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to get this to work with some restrictions that may or may not matter to you by inheriting from `current` and relying on shadowing: declare a local `fieldname` variable, create a local class that derives from the type you're checking, and inside a member function, check whether `fieldname` still refers to the local variable. If it does, no member `fieldname` exists.

```
#include <utility>
#include <stdio.h>

#define START(type) do { typedef type current; const char typeName[] = #type
#define HASMEMBER(fieldname) \
    []() -> bool { \
        struct HASMEMBER1 { } fieldname; \
        struct HASMEMBER2 : current { \
             static char TEST1(HASMEMBER1&); \
             static char (&TEST1(...))[2]; \
             auto TEST2() -> decltype(TEST1(fieldname)); \
        }; \
        return sizeof(std::declval<HASMEMBER2>().TEST2()) == 2; \
    }()
#define OUTPUT(fieldname) \
    printf("type of %s.%s is %s\n", typeName, #fieldname, \
        std::is_same<decltype(current::fieldname),int>::value ? "int" : \
        HASMEMBER(fieldname##Length) ? "Pascal string" : "C string")
#define END() } while (0)

struct Foo { int i; char *j; char *k; };
struct Bar { char *x; int y; };
struct Baz { char *x, *y, *z; int xLength, zLength; };

int main()
{
START(Foo);
  OUTPUT(i);  // type of Foo.i is int
  OUTPUT(j);  // type of Foo.j is C string
  OUTPUT(k);  // type of Foo.k is C string
END();
START(Bar);
  OUTPUT(x);  // type of Bar.x is C string
  OUTPUT(y);  // type of Bar.y is int
END();
START(Baz);
  OUTPUT(x);  // type of Baz.x is Pascal string
  OUTPUT(y);  // type of Baz.y is C string
  OUTPUT(z);  // type of Baz.z is Pascal string
END();
}
```

Edited to work on GCC 4.6.3. It is also still accepted by GCC 4.8.1 and clang 3.3, and should work with GCC 4.7.3 too (but not 4.7.2).

Comment: Looks good to me, but GCC 4.6.3 still doesn't accept it. This might be a GCC bug (and it might have been fixed in 4.7 or 4.8), but I wonder if there's a way to fix it so it'll work in 4.6...

Comment: @Quuxplusone That looks like it should be simple enough to work around. I'm not on a system that has GCC 4.6 installed right now, but I'll take a look when I am.

Comment: @Quuxplusone both your version and hvd's bomb out with an internal compiler error on GCC 4.7.2.

Comment: FYI, I think I have a working version now; it's giving me the error "template argument 1 is invalid" when I plug it into my whole system, but I *think* that error is unrelated to HAS_FIELD. I'll post the code later today. @SchighSchagh well that sucks. Anyone know if it's fixed in 4.8?

Comment: The trick to getting it working was to replace `decltype(f(fieldname))` with `char[sizeof f(fieldname)]`; GCC 4.6 has more bugs in decltype than it does in sizeof.

Comment: That wasn't the workaround I had in mind, but glad to read it works anyway :) BTW, I had tested my code with clang 3.3 and gcc 4.8.1, and it worked on both.

Comment: @Quuxplusone I've edited my answer to work with GCC 4.6, differently from how you changed it. GCC 4.6 doesn't support `this` references in function return types, but those aren't necessary if the overloaded function to call is static.

Comment: @hvd Verified that your new version works, although I don't understand how it avoids the GCC bug (only that it does). The reference to `TEST1(fieldname)` in the return type no longer means `this->TEST1(this->fieldname)`, but if `HASMEMBER(c,fieldname)` is going to yield `true`, then it *does* still mean `TEST1(this->fieldname)` (and GCC gives bogus errors if you put the `this->` in there explicitly). Weird...

Comment: @Quuxplusone That's a good point. Unfortunately, I cannot explain that, weird indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @hvd for [the clever idea of looking for either a local variable or an inherited member!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18927270/1424877) Here's the exact code I eventually got working on GCC 4.6.3:

```
#include <utility>
#include <stdio.h>

#define START(type) do { typedef type current; const char typeName[] = #type
#define HASMEMBER(fieldname) \
    []()->bool { \
        char fieldname; \
        struct HASMEMBER2 : current { \
             auto TEST2() -> char[sizeof(fieldname)]; \
        }; \
        return sizeof(std::declval<HASMEMBER2>().TEST2()) != 1; \
    }()
#define OUTPUT(fieldname) \
    printf("type of %s.%s is %s\n", typeName, #fieldname, \
        std::is_same<decltype(current::fieldname),int>::value ? "int" : \
        HASMEMBER(fieldname##Length) ? "Pascal string" : "C string")
#define END() } while (0)


struct Foo { int i; char *j; char *k; };
struct Bar { char *x; int y; };
struct Baz { char *x, *y, *z; int xLength, zLength; };

int main()
{
START(Foo);
  OUTPUT(i);  // type of Foo.i is int
  OUTPUT(j);  // type of Foo.j is C string
  OUTPUT(k);  // type of Foo.k is C string
END();
START(Bar);
  OUTPUT(x);  // type of Bar.x is C string
  OUTPUT(y);  // type of Bar.y is int
END();
START(Baz);
  OUTPUT(x);  // type of Baz.x is Pascal string
  OUTPUT(y);  // type of Baz.y is C string
  OUTPUT(z);  // type of Baz.z is Pascal string
END();
}
```

Notice that this approach cannot distinguish a 1-byte-long `char xLength` from a lack of `xLength`. For my application, this is acceptable; all my `xLength` fields are either 4 bytes long or nonexistent.

Notice that this `HASMEMBER` works only on non-private member *variables*; it shouldn't be used to test for private members (duh) or member *functions*. Again, this is acceptable for my application.

For the record, GCC 4.6.3 has bugs that make it refuse to compile `auto member_func() -> decltype(data_member)`, but it's happy with `auto member_func() -> char[sizeof data_member]`.

Comment: You could simply make `fieldname` be extremely large and quirky in size, like `0x31337` (note: odd is important).  Might be safer than `1`.  Then, as an unused variable, it should be discarded and never created...

Comment: @Yakk I considered that, but didn't want to permit the compiler to leave a big object on the stack if it *didn't* get optimized out for whatever reason.

Comment: put it in a local block, ensure that it is left uninitialized.  Then at worse it is two stack pointer movements (up and down) local to the macro 'body'.

Comment: @Yakk Yes, and if those movements cause %rsp to leave the current thread's allocated stack [let's talk hugely multithreaded application, which means tiny stacks], and the process receives a signal while %rsp is that garbage value, terrible things happen. IMHO it's just better not to create huge objects at all, if one can avoid it (and in this case one can). But it's also not a big deal.