# Get the type of & for built-in and operator&()?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, template-meta-programming, addressof

**Edit:** The answer I've marked below isn't 100% correct, that's actually in a comment: `using TPtr = decltype(&std::declval<T&>());`

---

I'm trying to use `std::conditional<>` to get the type of `&T`, where `T` may have `operator&()`, or not.

The simple solution is to not even try, instead specify another template argument:

```
struct Foo
{
    int operator&() { return 314; }
};

struct Bar { };

template <typename T, typename TPtr = T*>
struct A
{
    T& _t;
    A(T& t) : _t(t) {}
    TPtr data() {
        return &_t;
    }
};
```

where client code is then

```
Foo foo;
A<Foo, int> aFoo(foo);
int pFooData = aFoo.data();

Bar bar;
A<Bar> aBar(bar);
Bar* pBarData = aBar.data();
```

But what I'd rather write is something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct B
{
    using TPtr = typename std::conditional<has_operator_address_of<T>::value, typename std::result_of<decltype(T::operator&)&()>::type, T*>::type;

    T& _t;
    B(T& t) : _t(t) {}
    TPtr data() {
        return &t;
    }
};
```

where `has_operator_address_of` is modeled after [`is_call_possible`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17202010/8877).  Client code is then

```
B<Foo> bFoo(foo); // no need to second template argument
pFooData = bFoo.data();
```

but then the class without `operator&()` fails to compile:

```
B<Bar> bBar(bar);
pBarData = bBar.data();
```

It seems that `conditional` wants to compile both template arguments, so compilation fails when `T` doesn't have `operator&()`.  I've tried sprinkling `std::enable_if` around, but to no avail.

Comment: I don't understand why GCC rejects `using TPtr = decltype(&std::declval<int>());`. I thought the argument to `decltype` was supposed to be an unevaluated context? Just allow me to use `&` to get the resulting type, gosh darnit!

Comment: Not until I know it's correct. VS allows all sorts of non-standard things.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `std::declval<int>()` is an xvalue. `&` can only be used on lvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `decltype` and `declval`, with a little hackery to force an *lvalue* to be passed to the `&` operator (which is required):

Start with `#include <utility>` and define the following helper function:

```
template <typename T>
T& as_lvalue(T&& val)
{
    return val;
}
```

Then:

```
using TPtr = decltype(&as_lvalue(std::declval<T>()));
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1cb1c727cb701012))

Comment: @T.C. Goddammit I hate this stupid language. You go for it: I'll leave my silly hack up :P