# Switching between std::to_string() and .toString() depending upon template type

Tags: c++, string, templates, c++11

I'm currently programming my own `PriorityQueue` data structure in C++ which I have made into a template class with `typename T`.

The `toString()` member function of my class is defined as:

```
/**
 * @brief Gives a std::string representation of this queue structure
 *
 * The priority queue is returned as a string in the following format:
 *
 * \code{.cpp}
 * Data Item        Priority
 * [Item]           [P1]
 * [Item]           [P2]
 * [Item]           [P3]
 * \endcode
 *
 * where P1 < P2 < P3.
 *
 * @return String representation of this priority queue
 */
std::string toString() const {

    std::string tempString = "";

    // initialise temporary node to front of priority queue
    PQNode<T>* tempNode = front;

    // append string with headers
    tempString += "Data Item \t\t Priority\n";

    // while tempNode is not null, continue appending queue items to string
    while (tempNode != nullptr) {

        tempString += std::to_string(tempNode->head) + "\t\t\t " + std::to_string(tempNode->priority) + "\n";

        // shift tempNode to tail of current tempNode (moving along queue)
        tempNode = tempNode->tail;

    }

    return tempString;

}
```

How could I code this such that `std::to_string()` is used within this method if the type of the template is a primitive such as an `int` or `double` and `.toString()` (calling the toString method of the passed class) is called if the type of the template is a class with its own `toString` member function?

I presume there is a way to do it with `#ifndef` clauses however I don't have much experience using these.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, why do this when there is `std::priority_queue`?

Second, it's usually a design error to have a `toString` member function, because it hard-wires data logic with data presentation. What you should do instead is to overload `operator<<` for your class such that you can pass instances to any `std::ostream`.

Third, what you have asked for is to choose at compile time the "correct" string-conversion function depending on whether or not the type has a `toString` member function, and use `std::to_string` as a fallback. This can be achieved quite nicely in C++11 with a bit of template and `auto` magic. Here's an example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Example
{
    std::string toString() const { return "foo"; }
};

template <class T>
auto ToString(T const& t) -> decltype(t.toString())
{
    std::cout << "Using toString\n";
    return t.toString();
}

template <class T>
auto ToString(T const& t) -> decltype(std::to_string(t))
{
    std::cout << "Using std::to_string\n";
    return std::to_string(t);
}

int main()
{
    Example e;
    std::cout << ToString(e) << "\n";

    int i = 0;
    std::cout << ToString(i) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Using toString
foo
Using std::to_string
0
```

See also [C++11 ways of finding if a type has member function or supports operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201329/c11-ways-of-finding-if-a-type-has-member-function-or-supports-operator) (and especially the answer by user "zah").

---

Still, I strongly recommend implementing the `operator<<` approach instead.

Comment: Well, I'm mostly doing this for the fun of it, to practice writing data structures in C++ (I like to keep the knowledge fresh) and also for a personal project in which I'd like to have more functions for a priority queue than the STL version.  Thanks for the information, I'll look into overloading the << operator then.

Comment: This scales quite well. It is also nice to see how simple SFINAE bevomes with trailing return types and `decltype`. An alternative solution: implementing non-member `to_string` overloads, and then doing an ADL + "using std::to_string` thing, as is commonly done with `swap`.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury: "more functions" sounds ungood. The standard C++ way of adding more functions is, well, to add more functions :) And by that I mean free-standing template functions operating with iterators, just like all the ones in `<algorithm>`. The goal is to make your functions work with *any* container class that can act as a priority queue.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use function overloads. Use a function template for all types that have a `toString` function. Use other overloads for types that need to use `std::to_string`.

```
template <typename T
std::string toString(T const& obj)
{
   return obj.toString();
}

std::string toString(int obj)
{
   return std::to_string(obj);
}

std::string toString(double obj)
{
   return std::to_string(obj);
}
```

and then use

```
tempString += toString(tempNode->head) + ... ;
```

in `PriorityQueue::toString`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the next pattern which has been established with `std::swap`:

For all your user types define a non-member `to_string` function in the same namespace where the user type itself is defined. This function may  call the member `toString` :

```
std::string to_string(const UserType& x) {
    return x.toString();
}
```

Then in your function call `to_string` like this:

```
some_function() {
    ...
    using std::string;
    ...
    tempString += to_string(tempNode->head) ... // note: unqualified to_string!
}
```

This solution makes use of a C++ feature called `ADL` (argument-dependent lookup). You can read more about it here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl